# Buddypress preload page before registration

Tags: registration, buddypress, privacy-policy

Good day, Please i am working on a buddypress project and i want to add a Site Rule content before the registration page. i.e. when a user clicks on REGISTER, a page will be displayed to them showing them the site rules and they would have to check a box and click continue button which will open up the buddypress register page.

I don't know if there is(are) plugin(s) that can do something like it (a plugin that can display a content before the actual page) or how i can do achieve this.

Thanks